# Windows Form Combobox Selecteditem

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

when editing a specific record in a listview row, how do I get that value to the corresponding combobox selected item/value?

The combobox is in dropdownlist style mode, so the selected text wont work.

i tried this:

```
cbBrand.SelectedItem = lvMain.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].ToString();
```

but i get `null` in the corresponding combobox selecteditem... :(

Comment: what if you don't '`.ToString()`' the sub-item ?

Comment: @Seb cbBrand.SelectedValue = lvMain.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1]; gets me Unable to cast object of type 'ListViewSubItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Comment: I was asking for `.SelectedItem` instead of `.SelectedValue`

Comment: @Seb nothing happens.. because it's passing a value... the ComboBox is configured like this:
cb.DataSource = dt;
            cb.DisplayMember = "name";
            cb.ValueMember = "id";
so it is expecting a value, and the item i think it's the name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
int xcb;
xcb = this.cbBrand.FindString(lvMain.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text);
this.cbBrand.SelectedIndex = xcb;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectedValue property.

Comment: cbBrand.SelectedValue = lvMain.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].ToString(); gets me Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: cbBrand.SelectedValue = lvMain.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1]; gets me Unable to cast object of type 'ListViewSubItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'.